# How to pass variables from ActionLink in ASP.NET MVC with Kendo UI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-asp.net-mvc

There is this Home View, calling Production View using ActionLink.

```
<b>Start Date</b>
@(Html.Kendo().TextBox().Name("startDate"))
<b>End Date</b>
@(Html.Kendo().TextBox().Name("endDate"))
@(Html.ActionLink("Production","Index","Production"))
```

On click of the Link the contents of the 2 textboxes (startDate, and endDate) need to be passed  so that they are used by this controller called Production .

```
public class ProductionController : Controller
   {

    readonly Data.OPMSProductionEntities _opms = new Data.OPMSProductionEntities();

    public ActionResult Index() {
           return View();
     }


    public JsonResult Get([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
      {

          var products = ConvertOutputOfAdminAssociateSPToAList(startDate,endDate);

          return this.Json(products.ToDataSourceResult(request));
       }
```

This is the Kendo Grid which displays data in the Production view

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Production>().Name("Production").Columns(c => {
    c.Bound(p => p.Sl_No).Width(1);
    c.Bound(p => p.DateProcessed).Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy}");
    c.Bound(p => p.Remarks);
    c.Bound(p => p.RequestedAmount).Format("{0:c}");
    })
    .DataSource(d => d
        .Ajax()
        .Read(r => r.Action("Get", "Production"))
        .PageSize(8)
```

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink("Production","Index","Production")` is calling the method `Index`, not `Get`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke The Get is in the Grid which is in the view of Production.I have hard coded the dates which i hope to get from the calling view.

Comment: Yes I know, but you said you added the parameters to the 'Get()` method, but that's not the action method you are calling when you click the link so its not clear what your wanting to pass and to where. Do you want to pass the values to the `Index()`method?

Comment: You will need to use javascript/jquery to build the url. I'll post example shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to pass the dynamic values of the textboxes, you will need to construct the url using javascript.

Change you action link to give it an ID (or manually create it)

```
<a id="MyLink" href="#">Production</a>
```

Script

```
$('#MyLink').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "Production")';
  window.location.href = url + '?startDate=' + $("#startDate").val() + '&endDate=' + $("#endDate").val();
});
```

then change your Index method

```
public ActionResult Index(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
  ....
}
```

Comment: I had to include the # symbol in the $("#startDate")"

Comment: @Chakra, Sorry, forgot the hashtag! should be `$("#startDate")...`